# Can I pass multiple components within connect redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I would like to have a smart component/container that handles CRUD operations for Product entity and I have the following code:

```
function productContainerRender(WrappedComponent) {
    return class extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.fetchProducts = this.fetchProducts.bind(this);
        }

        fetchProducts = (page) => {
            this.props.dispatch(fetchProductsBegin());
            productsApi.getAll(page)
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.data) {
                        this.props.dispatch(fetchProductsSuccess(response.data._embedded.companies));
                    } else {
                        this.props.dispatch(fetchProductsFailure({message: "Fetching products failed"}));
                    }
                });
        };

        componentDidMount() {
            // this.fetchProducts(1);
        }

        render() {
            // ... and renders the wrapped component with the fresh data!
            // Notice that we pass through any additional props
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} fetchProducts={this.fetchProducts} />;
        }
    }
}

const productSelector = createSelector(
    state => state.products,
    items => items,
    loading => loading,
    error => error,
);

const mapStateToProps = createSelector(
    productSelector,
    (products) => ({
        products,
    })
);

const ListProducts = productContainerRender(
    ListProductComponent
);

const AddProduct = productContainerRender(
    AddProductComponent
);

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ListProducts,AddProduct);
```

When I try to call  from App component, it always shows up

Any idea how to make it so I can export both ListProducts,AddProduct and call from anywhere on the app.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/647#issuecomment-285460734

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only pass one Component to connect. So, instead, you’d have to do two connects:

```
const ConnectedListProducts = connect(mapStateToProps)(ListProducts)
const ConnectedAddProduct = connect(mapStateToProps)(AddProduct)
```

Since you can have only one default export, you‘d have to use named export in this case or split up those two components in two files.

Answer (score 10):

You can’t return multiple component at the same time with one call `connect`, remember that you are `export default` and you should return only one single function/component, remember that `connect` only return one single component at time, so the way you can do it is like

```
export default {
  ListProduct: connect(mapStateToProps)(ListProducts),
  AddProduct: connect(mapStateToProps)(AddProduct)
}
```

So when importing the components you can do

```
import Components from ‘.../your/path’;
class MyView extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return <Components.ListProducts/>
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice "complete" example, for those needing a bit more assistance